# Batch based file/folder creation

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, filenames, creation

I have a lot of movies in different genre folders. What I want to do through a batch file is  create a folder for each movie in the same genre folder as where the movie is. For example:

```
/Movies/SciFi/
/Movies/SciFi/the matrix.avi
/Movies/SciFi/the matrix reloaded.mkv
/Movies/Comedy/
/Movies/Comedy/borat.avi
/Movies/Comedy/dinner for schmucks.avi
```

Basically I want to run a batch file from the parent folder Movies, scan for all *.mkv *.avi *.mp4 files in the genre folders and create folders based on the movie names. The name of the folders should be:

```
.(moviename without extension).backdrop
```

Ofcourse the folder shouldn't be created if it already exists. This is what I have so far:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 /b') do md .%%~nf.backdrop
```

This has some disadvantages though: I have to run it from within each genre folder and if a file-name has a space in it, this command will only catch everything up till the space, rendering the aboce command pretty much useless.

Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the /r option if you don't want to walk a hierarchy. Also, a simple if statement can avoid trying to create an already existing folder

```
for /D %%D in (\Movies\*) do for %%F in ("%%~D\*.avi" "%%~D\*.mkv" "%%~D\*.mp4") do (
  if not exist "%%~D\%%~nF.backdrop" md "%%~D\%%~nF.backdrop"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes will handle the spaces;

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\movies\" %%d in (.) do (
    pushd %%d
    echo now in %%d
    for %%f in (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4) do (
        md "%%~nf.backdrop"
    )
    popd 
)
```

This should create `SOMEMOVIE.backdrop` in the `Category\SOMEMOVE\` dir.

If you want them in the root just `md "..\%%~nf.backdrop"`

(This assumes there are no other subdirs in the movie dir as its recursive so would include them)

Comment: But there *will* be additional subdirs once this script has been run. Which means this solution can only be used once, so FOR /R not a good option. Also will give error message if directory already exists.

Comment: Then you can use `for /d %%d in ("c:\movies\*") do (...` instead and you can check for folder existence with `if exist` http://ss64.com/nt/if.html